# What does a round icon with a horizontal line in its middle show?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, notification-icons

I'm using a nightly build of CM13. I recently noticed this round icon with a horizontal line in its middle. The icon is located in the right side of the notification bar.

[image: screenshot]

What does that icon depict?

Answer (score 1):

"Do Not Disturb" was turned on, you can swipe down the status bar and toggle it on/off.  Settings for it would be for a specific duration, Until you turn this off.  You can opt for Total silence, Alarms only, or Priority only.